# TypeError: create_superuser() Django-Python

Tags: python, django

I have this model(it's all i wrote):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastn = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username  = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email    = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    city   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
```

*And when I try to sync (python manage.py syncdb)
I see this error:*

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes

Usuario: dulce

Email: dulce@dulce.com

Password:

Password (again):

**TypeError: create_superuser() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)**

*anyone can help me?*

*Sorry if you can't understand (I'm from mexico)*

Comment: Could you paste here tracebak? Run: `python manage.py syncdb --traceback`

Comment: Did you override a `create_superuser()` function in your `User` model? Did you add some `ForeignKey` to `REQUIRED_FIELDS`?

Answer (score 0):

**[Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/)**

**[Using Configurable User Models in Django](http://procrastinatingdev.com/django/using-configurable-user-models-in-django-1-5/)**

---

Ok  *@pancakes* I try with english, but my english is very bad.

You should define `MyUserManager` class inherits `BaseUserManager` and create `create_user` and `create_superuser` functions.

here is the link from I coding my own custom User model

(links above)

Comment: try to use English, please :-)